# How to run AR project code using Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, runtime-error, vuforia

I create a simple AR application. I run this app on my tablet using unity successfully. I try to generate code and use it. To do this, I click `File->Build Settings`, `Android` and check `Google Androdi Project`.

Then I open eclipse, click `file->import->general->existing project into workspace`. I run this project on eclipse. It throws many error on runtime. First error message is `Sensors - enable - sensor Accelerometer (handle 4) dis -> en`

My screenshot is below :

[image]

My project folder and files :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've done the following two steps in Unity:

- For the `ImageTarget > Image Target Behaviour` load the Imported asset and set the `Type` and `DataSet` to it respectively.
- For the `ARCamera > DataSet Load Behaviour` make sure you've checked the ImageTarget/ ImageTargets name that you will be using and mark it `Active`

Comment: I can't run my application using eclipse ide. Normally, It runs on unity and android phone.

Comment: To run this app using eclipse, I did [these steps](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Vuforia-Android-SDK).

Comment: That should've been enough! I don't understand why you're still experiencing problems.